# How to force CGI to double-quote cookie value

Tags: perl

For a simple demonstration, let's use the following Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw /:standard/;
use MIME::Base64;

# ...

my $cookie = cookie( -name    => 'token',
                     -value   => '"' . encode_base64($token, '') . '"',
                     -expires => '+1y',
                   );

print header( -status    => 302,
              'Location' => $uri,
              -cookie    => $cookie,
            );
```

---

This script results in the following HTTP header:

[image]

---

However, I expected

**Set-Cookie:** `token="lrv5Jy5KhkXb8qIWpgd3bA==";` path=/; expires=...

---

What should I do to get the desired cookie format?

Answer (score 3):

Quotes around the cookie value are optional. The [CGI module's](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/source/lib/CGI.pm#L2766) authors choose not to include quotes, nor provide an API option to turn them on.

Your attempt is trying to include the quotes are *part of the value* instead of as characters that delimit it.

If you want to include the optional quotes, then you'll need to reimplement the `cookie` sub.

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution #1:

```
print header( 
  -status      => 302,
  'Location'   => $uri,
  'Set-Cookie' => 'token="' . encode_base64($token, '') . '"; ' .
                  'path=/; expires=' . (POSIX::strftime 
                  "%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT", gmtime (time + 365*24*60*60)) # +1y
            );
```

---

##### Solution #2:

```
my $cookie = cookie( -name    => 'token',
                     -value   => '',
                     -expires => '+1y',
                   )
                   =~ s/=;/{ '="' . encode_base64($token, '') . '";' }/er;

print header( -status    => 302,
              'Location' => $uri,
              -cookie    => $cookie,
            );
```